# Azure Powershell pop up window gives an error

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I installed Microsoft Azure Powershell and I used to login with Login-AzureRmAccount. But recently when the pop-up window which asks the user name and password pops up it gives the following error:

An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line: 4
Char: 11587
Error: Member not found.
Code: 0
URL: https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.4146.1/content/cdnbundles/jquery.1.11.min.js

Any idea what is the issue?
I think this happened after I installed Visual Studio 2015.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide the full error? Output of `$error[0].Exception | format-list -force`.

Comment: The problem is not with the Login-AzureRmAccount. I am stuck in the pop-up browser page that this command opens.

Comment: Any chance you can post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: And clicking `yes` does what exactly?

Comment: I tried **yes** but the page remains blank.

Comment: I am also getting this error.  Have you resolved this yet?  I can't get connected to Azure in VS2013.  Same line, same char, same error.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Internet Explorer from 8 to 9 has resolved this error for me. You can download it from here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx